# Contextual type cannot be used with dictionary literal

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4

I have an array of dictionaries and just want to check if the array contains a certain value. However, I am getting this error message:

> Contextual type '([Double : Double]) throws -> Bool' cannot be used with dictionary literal

Code:

```
if stored.contains(where: ([YAngle : ZAngle])) { // Error on this line
    print("This data is already stored")
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of contains(where:) is incorrect. This is an example of usage of that function that will not cause a complier error:

```
if stored.contains(where: { (key, value) -> Bool in
    return true
}) {
    // no op
}
```

What you probably want to do to check whether or not the dictionary contains a key-value pair is simply:

```
if stored[YAngle] == ZAngle {
    print("This data is already stored")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`contains(where:)` takes a function as its argument.  It's meant to be used when the array's element type doesn't conform to the `Equatable` protocol or if you need to do additional logic as part of the check.  There's two ways you can do this:

`[Double:Double]` conforms to `Equatable`, so since you're just doing a simple comparison you can instead use `contains(_:)` (i.e. just remove the `where:`):

```
if stored.contains([YAngle : ZAngle]) {
    print("This data is already stored")
}
```

If you're doing a more complex check, or if your type didn't conform to `Equatable`, you would pass in a function instead:

```
if stored.contains(where: { dict in
    // Here you would do your logic and return a boolean based on the result.
    // If you really wanted to do it this way with your current data
    // you could do this:
    return dict == [YAngle:ZAngle]
}) {
    print("This data is already stored")
}
```

Comment: Side note: standard Swift convention is to always start variables with a lowercase letter.  It took me a while to figure out what was going on in your code because I thought `YAngle` and `ZAngle` were types rather than variables.  Use `yAngle` and `zAngle` instead.